# Continuous AutoFocus observers in Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, avcapturedevice

Do you know what observers I can add when using `continuousAutoFocus` in `AVCaptureDevice` eg:

```
videoCaptureDevice?.exposureMode = .continuousAutoExposure
videoCaptureDevice?.focusMode = .continuousAutoFocus
```

I would like to know when the hardware stops autofocusing so that I kan show some animations.

This code only works for `videoCaptureDevice?.focusMode = .autoFocus`:

```
videoCaptureDevice?.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "adjustingFocus", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.new, context: nil)
```

Thanks.

EDIT:

Here is the full code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    captureSession = AVCaptureSession()

    let videoInput: AVCaptureDeviceInput

    do {
        videoInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: videoCaptureDevice)

        if captureSession.canAddInput(videoInput) {
            captureSession.addInput(videoInput)

            let metadataOutput = AVCaptureMetadataOutput()

            if captureSession.canAddOutput(metadataOutput) {
                captureSession.addOutput(metadataOutput)

                metadataOutput.setMetadataObjectsDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue.main)
                metadataOutput.metadataObjectTypes = metadataOutput.availableMetadataObjectTypes // Use all metadata object types by default.

            } else {
                scanningActivationFailed()
                return
            }

            if (videoCaptureDevice?.isFocusModeSupported(.continuousAutoFocus))! {
                do {
                    if(try videoCaptureDevice?.lockForConfiguration()) != nil {
                        videoCaptureDevice?.exposureMode = .continuousAutoExposure
                        videoCaptureDevice?.focusMode = .continuousAutoFocus
                        videoCaptureDevice?.unlockForConfiguration()
                    }
                } catch {

                }
            }

            videoCaptureDevice?.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "adjustingFocus", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.new, context: nil)
            let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ScannerViewController.focusCapture(_:)))
            mainView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

            previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession);
            previewLayer.frame = view.layer.bounds;
            previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;
            mainView.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer);

            /*
            // Initialize code Frame to highlight the code
            codeFrameView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
            codeFrameView.layer.borderWidth = 2
            view.addSubview(codeFrameView)
            view.bringSubview(toFront: codeFrameView)
            */

            captureSession.startRunning()

        } else {
            scanningActivationFailed()
        }
    } catch {
        scanningActivationFailed()
    }
}
```

and

```
override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    if keyPath == "adjustingFocus" {
        if let changed = change?[NSKeyValueChangeKey.newKey] as? Bool {
            animateFocus(animate: changed)
        }
    }else
    {
        print(keyPath)
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to provide a more complete code listing and description of what does or does not happen. As it stands, your question is hard to answer.

Answer (score 0):

From what the documentation tells me, this is a simple boolean value. You should be notified every time it changes so you should be getting notifications whether it changes to true or false. Are you actually observing the values (it's not enough simply to add yourself as an observer - you have to override `observeValue(forKeyPath:of:change:context:)` as well)?

Comment: Sorry, `observeValue(forKeyPath:of:change:context:)` seems to be called allright, but not always. So i guess the code works. Its just a matter of the framework not always posting the event.

Comment: Please do as I asked above: edit your question and post your complete code. Also some debugging details (what values are passed into `observe...`, do they ever differ, are there any patterns to the 'sometimes', ...). Without this, we can only guess, which is a waste of everyone's time including your own. Help us help you.

Comment: Wow this is a really old thread but I would like to reiterate what @Nam has already said in the question. When we set the capture device focus mode to .continuousAutoFocus. The "adjustingFocus" observer is called only when drastic changes take place for example when camera is taken too close to the object we are trying to capture. Apart from that It doesn't call the observer at all. Seems like a weird behavior, as I can clearly see the focus adjusting when I alter the distance between the camera and the object in question, but observer is not being called.